# SQL statement - how to select INTERSECTING keys

Tags: mysql, database

i need a help to get the MY-SQL statement, which does:

On my site, people search the car that is, i.e.  color is "GREEN" and year is "2010".

i want to get the id of such cars. i have 2 tables (colors and dates).
i tried something like this, but it combines, instead of intersecting...

```
select carID from COLORS where color=green 
+
select carID from DATES where year=2010
```

i want to get the intersecting carIDs, that meet the criteria... 
how to do the correct query?

p.s. also, is performance better using such complex SQL query, rather then querying them individually and then executing PHP function to find intersecting carIDs?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: The performance of one single query will usually be better than sorting them out later. Let the query optimizer do its magic.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a join:

```
select * from COLORS as c
inner join DATES as d
on d.carID = c.carID
where c.color=green
and d.year=2010
```

Comment: please, how it will be with 3rd argument... lets add example for third argument too,ie:
manufacturer= mercedes ...
 thanks!

Comment: Well, which table is the manufacturer stored in? A third table called MANUFACTURERS?